# How to add just the base node in a listview as an item, is getting all the info

Tags: c#, .net, xml, nodes

I'm trying to read an XML and get the base node to add it in a listview, but is getting all the information of those nodes and is adding those information as an item.

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Servers>
  <MYSERVER>
    <Host>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</Host>
    <User>MyUser</User>
    <Password>MyPassword</Password>
    <Port>25</Port>
  </MYSERVER>
</Servers>
```

I just want to add "MYSERVER" into the listview but is adding all the information (Host, User, Password and Port).

This is What I'm doing:

```
private void frmTransmissionManagement_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XMLDoc.Load(XMLInterfaces);
    foreach (XmlNode node in XMLDoc.SelectSingleNode("Servers"))
    {                
         lvConnections.Items.Add(node.InnerText, 0);
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: What version of .Net?  Can you use XDocument (LINQ to XML)?

Comment: This is .NET 4.6 C# programming language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like XDocument, too.  This code worked for me, though.  I believe this is what you want.

```
        foreach (XmlNode node in XMLDoc.ChildNodes)
        {
            if (node.Name == "Servers")
            {


                foreach (XmlNode serverNode in node)
                {
                    string s = serverNode.Name;
                    MessageBox.Show(s);
                }

            }




        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `XDcoument` from `System.Xml.Linq` you can use something like the following:

```
doc.Element("Servers").Elements().Select(x => x.Name);
```

This returns just the string (actually in this case it's an `IEnumerable` with a single value): "MYSERVER".

A quick sample program I wrote demonstrates:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var doc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?> <Servers> <MYSERVER> <Host>xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx</Host> <User>MyUser</User> <Password>MyPassword</Password> <Port>25</Port> </MYSERVER> </Servers>");
    var servers = doc.Element("Servers").Elements().Select(x => x.Name);
    foreach(var s in servers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```